# ListBox fires lost focus event when lits ListBoxItem is selected, how to avoid this ?

Tags: wpf, listbox

ListBox fires lostfocus event when its ListBoxItem is selected, how to avoid this ? 
I want LostFocus to fire only when something else outside it receives focus.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, `ListBox` never gets the focus, only it`s items do, so for this to work we`ll have to use them. Probably there`s some elegant solution for this, but here`s my take.
This I placed in code behind of the `Window` that contains `ListBox`:

```
private void myListBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var focused = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);

   var item = focused as ListBoxItem;
   if (item == null || !lbMain.Items.Contains(item.DataContext))
   {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

The second check in `if` statement is in case other ListBoxes are present. If your scenario is more complex you most probably will have to add some tweaks: for example if two ListBoxes have the same `ItemsSource`.

Answer (score -1):

try to set on ListBoxItem the property Focusable to False. Eventually on elements inside your ListBoxItem DataTemplate.